# If I echo a statement and no one hears it, does it ever get echoed? (PHP cron job question)

Tags: php, apache, cron, echo

So I have a script that I debug with a bunch of echo statements. This is run every 3 minutes on my server by cron, and I sometimes leave the echo statements in there. They're not going to a browser, they're just going... anywhere?

This is a vague question I guess, but what happens when there's no end-user or output for an echo statement? Does it hog up memory? Does it just vanish? I'd appreciate any help in understanding this.

Comment: Upvoted for title poetry. :) (And mutual interest, but nevermind that.)

Comment: Yes, I agree with Agor, nice title!

Comment: You get points for title poetry?!! Well, yes, it's much better than some I've seen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is yes, and the output is mailed to the account that is running the cron task.  You can change this in the crontab file by setting a "MAILTO=accountname" option, like this example cron file:

```
MAILTO=root

# run a script every hour
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
#etc.
```

Any  output from the above cron task would be mailed to the root user.  As Mike B posted, you can also simply redirect the output elsewhere on the task line using the `>` operator:

```
01 * * * * php testscript.php > /var/log/logfile.log
```

in which case cron does not see it and does not send an email.

The bottom line is that if you leave some `echo` statements in a PHP script and set it as a cron job, then you will start getting emails from the cron daemon.

Comment: You can redirect to `/dev/null`, if you don't want to keep the output. It'll still get printed, but it'll immediately be discarded, thereby not taking up any memory.

Comment: @troelskn - definitely a popular strategy.

Comment: So I found I was using 75% of my diskspace quota on that server, and looked and looked.... and found 3 gigs of mail in the maildir directory. So there you go!

Comment: @AlexMcp 4 gigs. Might want a better server.

Answer (score 9):

Yes they are outputted <strike>but to noone in particular</strike> (See [zombat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320325/if-i-echo-a-statement-and-no-one-hears-it-does-it-ever-get-echoed-php-cron-job/1320394#1320394), it's mailed to the owner of the crontask). You can write the output of your script to a file via:

```
php myscript.php > /var/log/cronlog.log
```

(Assuming you're using linux since you said cron and not scheduled task)

Comment: And are they held in memory or anything bad like that? Or is forgetting to comment out a few echos no big deal?

Comment: @Alex: They go into the STDOUT buffer, so yes, they are kept in memory. But it is periodically flushed out and has a maximum size. The mem leak wouldn't be your echo statements.

Comment: As stated by zombat, the output is mailed to the owner of the cron job.  It's usually a system account, and thus sometimes hard to find if you have virtual addresses and such.